# Power Automate Reminder Flow for SharePoint Library

Tags: power-automate, flow, reminder, if-condition, email-notification

I have a SharePoint Online Document Library that I'd like to send a reminder email 7 days after a file is uploaded.  How can I set the flow to look at the 'Created' date, add 7 days, then send an email to the 'Created By' user?

Thank you

Comment: Use a schedular flow that runs daily and filter the documents from library with your created date conditions to send emails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a scheduled flow as recommended in the comment by Dikesh Gandhi. The alternative would be to have a flow that triggers when the document is uploaded, then use the Delay action to wait for 7 days, and then send the email.

The scheduled flow would be slightly more complicated to implement, but it's the better choice if lots of documents will be uploaded to the library.

[image]